# How can I change the color of a line loop in OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am drawing a simple rectangular line loop using this call:

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_LINE_LOOP,
                    numIndices, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                    getIndicesBuffer());
```

Now, the color of this line loop is black. How can I change it to another color? Red, for example.

Comment: change the fragment shader

Comment: @ratchetfreak can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change your fragment shader, I am going to assume you want to change the color per line loop.

change your fragment shader to this:

```
uniform vec4 color;

main(){
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

And before each glDrawElements you can then call `GLES20.glUniform4f(colorLoc, r, g, b, a);`. Where `colorLoc` is the return value of `GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color");` and r, g, b and A are the red, green, blue and alpha values in the range 0-1 of the color you want.

Comment: what are the parameters of `GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "color")` ? What are "program" and "color"?

Comment: color is a String (the same as the name of the uniform in the shader) and program is the identifier of the program you put the shader in.

Comment: thanks man! however i am still not sure what to use for `program`. I am using all this inside a method `renderFrame()`. I think I dont even have a shader

Comment: if you ever call `glCreateProgram` then you have a program

Comment: thanks, i think I found the "program". But that only gives me an id (int). How can I now figure out what "color" is?

Comment: Can I use the program id to figure out what the string is?

Comment: the string is exactly `"color"` if you used the shader in my answer. It is defined by the `uniform vec4 color;` line

Comment: sorry, but how do I use your code above? is that class, method ... ?

Comment: by the way, I am using this in an android project